# vue3 typescript question. what type is lazy-loading vue-router?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, vue-router, vuejs3

```
export default {
  path: '/about',
  name: 'About',
  // route level code-splitting
  // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
  // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
  component: (): Promise<any> => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../../views/About.vue'),
};
```

I am using Vue3 & vue-router & eslint air-bnb,

the eslint check says i need to
set the right type, how do i check the type and what type should fill to avoid the eslint check? many thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct return type is `Promise<RouteComponent>`

```
import { RouteComponent } from "vue-router";

export default {
  path: '/about',
  name: 'About',
  component: (): Promise<RouteComponent> => import('../../views/About.vue'),
};
```

Comment: `RouteComponent` is not defined in `vue-router`

Comment: @Chu [It does exists](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/master/src/types/index.ts#L185), but only on vue-router next (v4.x) which I assume is the version that OP use because he mentioned that he's using Vue 3. You might be using vue-router v3 for Vue 2